# MVC3. Browser alerts by itself when returning 500 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, http-status-codes

Hello how to prevent browser from alerting by itself, when returning a  `HttpStatusCodeResult` object.

The Action Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Finish()
    {
        //Throw the status code result          
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500,"Oops something wrong happened!");
    }
```

The script

```
           jQuery.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Finish","Home")',
                type: "POST",
                success : function(result) {
                    alert("success is:"+result);
                },
                error: function (response, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

The result of calling **Finish()** Action is displayed in the `alert();` function, but
under the custom alert,
**The browser also alerts with a message** - "*The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.*"

### SOLUTION

The actual problem was, as #tanathos pointed out, a global function:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
if (jqxhr != null) {
    alert(jqxhr.responseText);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help. Question Closed.

Comment: try catch blocks are what you are looking for

Comment: Check customErrors tag in system.web in your Web.config file, does it have defaultRedirect attribute? maybe it redirects to page which provides alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe somewhere in your project there's already a lower level catch for ajax errors, like an ajaxSetup or an [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).

Also, is jQuery the only framework implemented?